# ChainedTransactionManager analogue

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I'm using ChainedTransactionManager in my project, but it's been marked @Deprecated recently. I would like to know if there is any analogue for a linked transaction from two databases.

JtaTransactionManager with Atomikos is not my case apparently.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ChainedTransactionManager, you can register a TransactionSynchronization to explicitly follow transaction cleanup with simplified semantics in case of exceptions.

- AbstractReactiveTransactionManager which implements
  ReactiveTransactionManager, Serializable

  This base class provides the following workflow handling:
- determines if there is an existing transaction;
- applies the appropriate propagation behavior;
- suspends and resumes transactions if necessary;
- checks the rollback-only flag on commit;
- applies the appropriate modification on rollback
- triggers registered synchronization callbacks.